# How to print only the stderr_lines when shell command execution fails in ansible playbook task

Tags: ansible

In my ansible playbook I have a task that executes a `shell` command. One of the parameters of that command is password. When the shell command fails, ansible prints the whole json object that includes the command having password. If I use `no_log: True` then I get censored output and not able to get `stderr_lines`. Is there a way to customize the output when shell command execution fails?

Comment: No. There is no way to customize it and selectively censor part of the command. It's a bad practice to put plain-text passwords to a command-line.

Comment: Password is encrypted via Ansible vault but decrypted before using in this scenario.

Comment: Could you use become:yes to avoid sending plain text passwords? I.e. does the super user have to use a password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take advantage of ansible [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) and their error handling feature.

Here is an example playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Block demo for shell
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    
    - block:

        - name: my command
          shell: my_command is bad
          register: cmdresult
          no_log: true

      rescue:

        - name: show error
          debug:
            msg: "{{ cmdresult.stderr }}"

        - name: fail the playbook
          fail:
            msg: Error on command. See debug of stderr above
```

which gives the following result:

```
PLAY [Block demo for shell] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [my command] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result", "changed": true}

TASK [show error] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/bin/sh: 1: my_command: not found"
}

TASK [fail the playbook] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error on command. See debug of stderr above"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

Comment: block-rescue is a good idea. Be careful, the registered variable with the password will be available in *`hostvars`*. (my 2 cents)

Comment: Possibly a better way to generate an erroring shell: `shell: >&2 echo "This is an example message" && /bin/false` :)

Comment: @VladimirBotka +1 But possibly, here, the password is in the playbook YAML already (if not vaulted)

Comment: Interesting idea. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That password is vaulted but the variable is replaced while executing the command. Another possibility is to restructure the scripts and playbooks to not send the password at all as a command param.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize something like this :

```
- name: Running it
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: failing the task
      shell: sh a.sh > output.txt
      ignore_errors: true
      register: abc

    - name: now failing
      command: rm output.txt
      when: abc|succeeded
```

stdout will be written to a file. If it's a failure you can check the file and debug it, if it's a success then file will be deleted.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Only problem is password will still be there. Can however read the file content and remove after printing appropriate texts.

Comment: I would consider this an even bigger risk, if the playbook fails somehow in the middle of the create/remove file process, then you are left with a file containing your password on the remote host... Silencing the output could be a solution if that works `shell: sh a.sh > /dev/null`