# How to avoid leaking credentials with ansible shells commands and avoid no_log issues?

Tags: security, ansible

Even if apparently Ansible allow use of `stdin` for passing credentials to executed commands it seems that it still exposes them in at least two places:
* `invocation.module_args.stdin`
* `item` when using loops.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- hosts: n0
  vars:
    logins:
      localhost:5000:
        testuser: testpassword
  tasks:

    - block:

        - name: Perform container registry login(s)
          become: true
          command: >
            podman login --username={{ lookup('dict', item.value).key }}
                        --password-stdin
                        {{ item.key }}
          args:
            stdin: "{{ lookup('dict', item.value).value }}"
          loop: "{{ query('dict', logins) }}"
          register: result
          no_log: true

      always:
        - debug: var=results
```

In a case like this credentials are exposed in two places:

```
TASK [login] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [n0] (item=None) => {
    "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result",
    "changed": true
}
fatal: [n0]: FAILED! => {
    "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result",
    "changed": true
}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [n0] => {
    "registry_login_podman": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": [
                    "podman",
                    "login",
                    "--username=testuser",
                    "--password-stdin",
                    "localhost:5000"
                ],
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "podman login --username=testuser\n            --password-stdin\n            localhost:5000\n",
                        "_uses_shell": false,
                        "argv": null,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": "testpassword",
                        "stdin_add_newline": true,
                        "strip_empty_ends": true,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "key": "localhost:5000",
                    "value": {
                        "testuser": "testpassword"
                    }
                },
                "msg": "non-zero return code",
                "rc": 125,
                "start": "2019-09-16 10:33:09.228621",
                "stderr": "Error: error authenticating creds for \"localhost:5000\": pinging docker registry returned: Get https://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused",
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "Error: error authenticating creds for \"localhost:5000\": pinging docker registry returned: Get https://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused"
                ],
                "stdout": "",
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The big question is how to secure this operation? Please do not mention using podman specific modules but that question is about finding a generic way to expose credentials that needs to be passed to command running on remote machine **without hiding the stdout/stder of that tool**, as this may contain essential information.

Comment: And it also lands in the `hostsvars` as pointed in the first comment of this answer recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921338/2123530

Comment: If you think your question in another light, I would say, as said on the question linked above, what you are trying to do is higly insecure by nature and should be avoided. e.g. if you would run that command in a shell, your password would end in your `.bash_history`

Comment: It looks like you want to use ansibles vault functions:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#

If all you are doing is pulling variables that are written down in a variable file somewhere, and you don't want it showing up plaintext, ansible can use the vault to encrypt it all.

Here is an example of it in use that might help too:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/ansible/variable-vault